# How Could the Estimates Obtained through OLS and GLS Vary in Their 95% Confidence Interval Values While They Have the Same P-Value?

Tags: time-series, regression, confidence-interval, p-value

I am working on an interrupted time series analysis. The data actually meet most of the assumptions of the OLS (the outcome variable is normally distributed, the Beusch-Pagan test of the residuals of the linear regression show homoscedasticity, the Durbin-Watson test shows no auto-correlation). From the OLS model, I found the following results:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------   |
|olsmodel <- lm(outcomevar ~ idv1p + idv2r+ idv3t, data=itsdata)
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------   |
|Variables  |  Estimates (95% Confidence interval) |Std. errors|t-value |Pr(>|t|)    | 
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | 
|(Intercept)|28.68111 [27.92314229, 29.43907888]   |0.38088    |75.303  |< 2e-16***  |
|idv1p      |1.14166 [-0.00457623, 2.28788806]     |0.57598    |1.982   |0.0509 .    |  
|idv2r      |-0.02660 [-0.07605110, 0.02284135]    |0.02485    |-1.071  |0.2875      |   
|dv3t       |-0.07292 [-0.09985373, -0.04599294]   |0.01353    |-5.389  |6.97e-07 ***|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The OLS model shows that idv1p has no significant effect because the 95% CI includes 0 and the p-value is slightly above 0.05. However, the GLS model I run with ARMA(0, 0) (shown below) has the same p-value as the above but the 95% CI shows significant effect.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
glsarma00 <- gls(outcomevar ~ idv1p + idv2r+ idv3t, data=itsdata method="ML")   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Variables  |Estimates (95% Confidence interval)  |Std. errors |t-value   |Pr(>|t|)                |  
|(Intercept)|28.68111 [27.93460645, 29.42761472]  |0.3808765   |75.30292  |0.0000                  |
|idv1p      |1.141656 [0.01276037, 2.27055146]    |0.5759777   |1.98212   |0.0509                  |
|idv2r      |-0.026605 [-0.07530323, 0.02209349]  |0.0248466   |-1.07077  |0.2875                  |
|dv3t       |-0.072923 [-0.09944641, -0.04640025] |0.0135324   |-5.38878  |0.0000                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         |
AIC= 288.2094; BIC=300.3635; logLik= -139.1047
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How could the discrepancy happen? Which model should I pick?

Comment: Which functions did you use to create those tables?

Comment: I used the function  lm(outcomevar ~ idv1p + idv2r+ idv3t, data=itsdata) to create the first model; and gls(outcomevar ~ idv1p + idv2r+ idv3t, data=itsdata method="ML")  to create the second model

Comment: But how did you create the summary tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio of the lengths to the upper bounds are (29.43907888 - 28.68111) / (29.42761472 - 28.68111)  which is  1.015357. This is exactly `qt(.975, df = 80) / qnorm(.975)` so it may be the difference between using a t-distribution and a normal distribution for the CI.

> Which model [method/function?] should I pick?

The one that uses the t-distribution. The two models are the same though.

Comment: There is one difference between the OLS model (first table) and the GLS model(second table) pertaining to the idv1p variable. Though the P-values are the same for the variable in both models (0.0509), the 95% CI of the OLS model is statistically not significant (-0.00457623, 2.28788806) whereas, the variable is significant in the GLS model (0.01276037, 2.27055146).

Comment: My point is that the parameter estimates are the same. Thus, the statistical models are the same (also clear from the `lm` and `gls` call). The only difference is the confidence intervals' widths which seems to be caused by how these are computed. I presume that this has nothing to do with the choice of statistical model but rather which function you used to create the two tables.

Comment: I used the nlme generic function in R to create the GLS model and lm function to create the OLS.